# Python to read xml

Tags: python-3.x

I am no able to make python to read xlm info. Please see my xml Line bellow. Do not seems to be normal as other I have seen before.

```
b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>\n<mtsInputForm source="None">\n    <type>2109</type>\n    <serial>000777R</serial>\n    <xmlMessages>\n        <xmlMessage type="system"/>\n        <xmlMessage type="error" num="1">No information was found matching the search criteria.</xmlMessage>\n    </xmlMessages>\n</mtsInputForm>\n'
```

I need to get this message "No information was found matching the search criteria" from the XML line above.
How do I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I parse XML in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912434/how-do-i-parse-xml-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out....

```
XML_line = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>\n<mtsInputForm source="None">\n    <type>2109</type>\n    <serial>000777R</serial>\n    <xmlMessages>\n        <xmlMessage type="system"/>\n        <xmlMessage type="error" num="1">No information was found matching the search criteria.</xmlMessage>\n    </xmlMessages>\n</mtsInputForm>\n'''
source = str.encode(XML_line)
root = ET.fromstring(source)
for msg in root.findall(".//xmlMessage"): #xlm has two tgs with same name "xmlMessage" 
    information = msg.text
            if info_typee == str:
                info_list.append(info)
                print (information)
```

xlm has two tgs with same name "xmlMessage" and the code above bring both information, one is type = class the other is str

Answer (score 0):

Check this example from `Python Cookbook` on how to `Parse Simple XML Data` (Section 6.3):

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from xml.etree.ElementTree import parse

# Download the RSS feed and parse it
u = urlopen('http://planet.python.org/rss20.xml')
doc = parse(u)

# Extract and output tags of interest
for item in doc.iterfind('channel/item'):
  title = item.findtext('title')
  date = item.findtext('pubDate')
  link = item.findtext('link')

  print(title)
  print(date)
  print(link)
```

Comment: All the example i see seems to very simple xml items name like the example that you showd me title -  pubDate - ,link....  but the one I have , has the following name that I have to extract data from       
<xmlMessage type="error" num="1">data i want</xmlMessage>